# how to change state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form, when I click on the button I have to show the message. The message has two states - **setMessageShown (true);** and **setMessageShown (true);**

How to change the state to **true** inside **handleSubmit** - **setMessageShown(true);**?

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // ...
};

const ReviewPopup = ({ name }) => {
  const [messageShown, setMessageShown] = useState(false);
  const hideMessage = () => {
    setMessageShown(false);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="new_review" id="new_review" action="/reviews" acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post">
    // ...
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put handleSubmit inside your component.

```
const ReviewPopup = ({ name }) => {
  const [messageShown, setMessageShown] = useState(false);
  const hideMessage = () => {
    setMessageShown(false);
  };

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMessageShown(true);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="new_review" id="new_review" action="/reviews" acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post">
    // ...
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: We don't need to use arrow function in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
const ReviewPopup = ({ name }) => {
    const [messageShown, setMessageShown] = useState(false);

    const hideMessage = () => {
        setMessageShown(false);
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        setMessageShown(true)
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="new_review" id="new_review" action="/reviews" acceptCharset="UTF-8" method="post">
        // ...
        </form>
   );
};
```

This is how you can change state inside the react hooks.

Here, using  `useState`, you are assigning a state variable and declaring a method with which you can change the state variable

`const [messageShown, setMessageShown] = useState(false);`

Here `messageShown` is the state variable and `setMessageShown` is the method with which you can change the state variable. That is what you are declaring in this line. The `useState(false)` means the initial value of the state variable `messageShown`.